# Java/Android class dependencies

Tags: java, android

So I've inherited a rather large Android project. I'm trying to pull out the parts of the app that are no longer needed.  Trouble is, there isn't anything I can remove that doesn't cause hundreds of compilation errors.  Every class references so many other classes that it's almost impossible to remove anything.  For example, if I delete an Activiy class, every other Activity in the project gets errors.

This is bad practice right?  I never really thought about it before.  Obviously some classes need to reference other classes (Controllers -> Views), but not to the point where every class is intertwined, right?

Comment: This is probably not a specific enough question for SO in its current form.  Your first task if you are serious about cleanup would probably be to document the specific dependencies and then categorize them as justified vs refactorable.  But beware resetting one brick turning leading to rebuilding an entire wall - if that is contemplated, at least use the current version to develop a document of the required functionality which could guide a theoretically cleaner design.

Comment: Yes, this is bad practice regardless of the language or the platform. Nothing unique to Android. The only reason that an Activity should have a dependency on another Activity is if it requests navigation through an Intent. You could move that sort of dependency (building the intent) to a separate class, so that no Activity references another one.

Comment: Or if it *extends* another subclass of Activity...

Comment: Undeleted the post. Was a little annoyed of the minus 1.

Comment: It might make fit better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: What's the actual question? "Is it bad to have a tangled mess of dependencies?" Of course it is.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the great advice.  I know I wasn't very specific, but there is a lot of code here.  But one example is that each Activity has the ability to start any other Activity in the app.  So if I have to remove one activity, I have to comment out every activity's call that started that specific Activity.

Dave, yes that is my general question. But is it not common to write a custom class that talks to another custom class?  And if all your classes do that, is that bad design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out proguard. You can configure it in a way, that only the used classes gets compiled.

*"It shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer."*

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Yes, for the compiled result - and it's possible it may have reports which give you some useful analysis of the dependencies.  But it won't directly solve source code readability/maintainability issues.

Comment: This would reduce the size of the apk, but would do nothing to improve maintainability of the application, which, I believe, is what OP is asking for.